# My iPhone won't stop asking for a credit card

Tags: ios

Every time I try to update a game it tells me their needs to be a verification is required. I'm putting in a credit card but it keeps on declining it. The credit card has money; I checked with the bank.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option labeled "No Creditcard" or "None". I have that enabled, which solves the problem for me.